# How to control jquery toggle?

Tags: jquery

```
var light = 'off';
$('#switch').toggle(function(){light='on'},function(){light='off'});


//in some case 
$('#something').mouseout(function(){light = 'off'});
```

For example I clicked the switch, then light is on, at that time I mouseout something, the light is off, I want to turn up the light again, and click the switch again, but the switch think the light is still on and execute light = off again. I have to click it twice to turn up the light , how to solve this problem?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case I don't think toggle will be enough, since you have an outside influence on the state you toggle.

And so:

```
var light = 'off';

function toggleLight() {
 if (light == "off")
   light = "on";
 else
   light = "off";
}

$('#switch').click(toggleLight);
$('#something').mouseout(function() { light = "off"; });
```

Comment: whenever I come to switch things ,toggle come up in my mind,I thought that should works,seems with outside influence it cannot,nows it works with click.